# Vuetify Datatable re-renderEvent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i have the following problem:
I am using vuetify data table with a remote server reqest to load the data.
Now i created a resize column js code in vanilla JS which is called after the remote data is loaded.

The problem is that after the remote data is loaded and i add the data to v-model, the table is rerendered in vuetify and the js code fetches the wrong DOM-HTML data in that moment (because it does not exist yet). My solution at the moment is to call the JS Code with a timeout with 200ms after the remote data is fetched. This works most of the time but is no clean solution.

So my question is, is there an event which is triggered after the vue table data is re-rendered? Or any suggestions how i can fix my problem?

Thanks
Pat

Comment: Have you tried to use the $nextTick method (instead of the timeout)?

Comment: Can't you try to turn the Vanilla code into Vue code?

Comment: @Maarten Veerman, and how to call the vue code then after the render?
Elise: not yet, i will look into it. Thanks for the tipp